# Get value from a dictionary who's value is an array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I am trying to get a value from a dictionary.

I have a dictionary that has 4 entries the 4th being an array of dictionaries.

I know the value I want is set in the last dictionary of the array.
 how can I obtain a valee from it?

```
myDict["a" : String, "b" : String, "c" : String, "d" : [ArrayofDict]]
```

in the ArrayofDict there is `["1" : String, "2" : String]`.

I want to obtain the second value of the the ArrayofDict.

At least I think it is this way. Below is an image of the data colected.

imgUrl being d in the example, and all the 4 values, that I thought was dictionaries, are the same with different text in the text = part

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be a dictionary with an array with 4 elements, for the key "imgUrl". Every element in the array seems to be having 2 parameters `text` and `size`. So i'm gonna refactor my answer according to that understanding.

```
guard let imageDict = myDict["imgUrl"] as? [Imagess] else { // Image being the Struct created to parse the Json from the website
    print("Dictionary not found!"
    return
}

guard let imageURL = imageDict.first?.text as? String else {
    print("url not found!")
    return
}

print(imageURL)
```

Comment: thank you for your time on this i updated my picture, after trying your answer it came back as nil for fourthEntery, wich made me look at it with a breakpoint and hover over the constant fourthEntery. it i set it to [Any} instead of [String:Any] then i get the image above when hovering over fourthEntery

Comment: @TonyMerritt check the edit. The last edit i forgot to change the casting. What type is the array? LastFM_Search.Images?

Comment: Thank you for your time on this, when i set it to any on the first one i get the 4 objects in the imageDict but it shows this(New image in OP) in the hover.

Comment: @TonyMerritt it seems you already have the array in that specific type. That last edit just might have solved the problem. Check my edit, it should work.

Comment: Exelent this was a great help, it turns out the Any needed to be Images, my struct that I had created to parse the JSON. Thanks you for your Time and help on this I appretiate it.

Comment: @TonyMerritt Since you also solved you can edit the answer and change the `Any` to the correct type. Go ahead suggest an edit to the answer :)